# Notations in philosophy and math regarding logic

Tags: logic, notation

I'm a philosophy student and I'm trying to write math statements in the logic formar which I'm more used to.

Is this correct?

[image]

Comment: the left statements are not true,  are you aware of this?

Comment: I'm not. Why is it not the case?

Comment: @trula $\mathbb N$ not $\mathbb R^+$. Though writing $x\ge 1$ rather than $x>0$ might reduce any confusion

Comment: Are you asking if the statements a well written or if they are true?

Comment: @bernard masse is the first line equivalent to the middle and last line in both rows?

Comment: Let $x= 0.5$. Then $x > 0$ but $x^2 = 0.25 < x$. So the statements on the left are not true. @Lucas Fernandes.

Answer (score 1):

$\forall x \in S:  P(x) ~~\equiv ~~ \forall x: [x\in S \to P(x)]$

$\exists x \in S: P(x) ~~ \equiv ~~ \exists x: [x\in S \land P(x)]$

Comment: Thank you. Short and precise.